# Jquery help regarding hiding selected div divs

Tags: jquery

i have say five divs with the layout as in the following code..

```
//Div one
<div class="container">
<div class="hide">
    <button class="hide" value="hide" />
</div>
</div>

//Div Two
<div class="container">
<div class="hide">
    <button class="hide" value="hide" />
</div>
</div>

//Div Three
< div class="container">
<div class="hide">
    <button class="hide" value="hide" />
</div>
</div>
```

now say i click the hide button in the second div, i want to hide the second div.. That is i want to hide the div corresponding to the button click.. 
How to do that via jquery only???

i tried using the 'this' keyword through jquery but that would hide all the containers and not just one.
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('button.hide').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest('.container').hide()
});
```

I specified `button.hide` instead of `.hide` as selector, because you have more different elements with that classname

See `closest()` usage on [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: It finds the closest parent with the given class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to traverse up the DOM tree to target the `<div>`. Then you can trigger the hide on the div.

```
$('button.hide').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').hide();
});
```

This, of course, is done on DOM ready: `$(document).ready(function() { /*...*/ });`